# how to print just the 'use%' column with all use % values by 'df -k' command

Tags: linux, aix

I want to print Use% column with all % value in 'df -k' command. I want to compare all those value to a variable value.

Comment: Are you using this in an AIX environment? (I noticed the tag)

Comment: Ankit, don't forget to accept any answer that solved your problem (as it appears Stéphane's has). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 df -kP | awk 'NR>1 && $5+0 >= 90'
```

Would list the entries (in the portable output format of `df` (with `-P`) that also guarantees all entries are on a single line) for which the `use%` is greater or equal to `90`. The `+0` is to force numeric comparison (otherwise `100%` would be considered less than `90`).

Comment: this gives a perfect solution .

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df -k|sed 's/  */\t/g;s/%//'|cut -f 5
```

You can then eliminate the first line and compare the values, but you have no more device relation at this point.

[EDIT:]
So I was right and you need the device. So you want something like this:

```
for item in `df -k|sed 's/  */_/g;s/%//'|cut -d_ -f 1,5`; do
  if (( ${item#*_} > 90 )); then
    echo ${item%_*} has ${item#*_}%
  fi
done
```

This is bash syntax. Adapt it for your needs.

Comment: One more question, let suppose I ran this command and I got output 10,20,30 and now I want to find that particular line which contains '20 '. and print the 'Mounted on' column of that particular line

Answer (score 0):

**With GNU df - Untested on aix**

You can have the Use% values without parsing `df` output:

```
df --output=pcent
```

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks! I edit the answer with that highlight